# Trouble reading JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON object that I am trying to read using Python but I am having some issues. I have a file named "test.txt" which contains the received JSON object. The contents of "test.txt" are as follows:

```
{ "Sections": {"Now": "Thursday 3 February 2011 08:31",  "Section": [ { "Article": [ {"audioCounter": 0, "commentsCounter": 0, "Exceprt": "Category 5 cyclone slams into flood-hit Queensland", "hasMore": "true", "ID": 44871, "important": "False", "likesCounter": 0, "photoCounter": 0, "time": "20:58", "timeStamp": "2\/2\/2011 8:59:37 PM", "timeStatus": "True", "Title": "Category 5 cyclone slams into flood-hit Queensland", "Type": "Politics", "videoCounter": 0, "viewsCounter": 2 }, {"audioCounter": 0, "commentsCounter": 0, "Exceprt": "The White House: Egypt must begin a peaceful and orderly transition of power immediately", "hasMore": "false", "ID": 44868, "important": "True", "likesCounter": 0, "photoCounter": 0, "time": "20:51", "timeStamp": "2\/2\/2011 8:52:28 PM", "timeStatus": "True", "Title": "The White House: Egypt must begin a peaceful and orderly transition of power immediately", "Type": "Politics", "videoCounter": 0, "viewsCounter": 0 }, {"audioCounter": 0, "commentsCounter": 0, "Exceprt": "Bazzi: Berri endeavors to facilitate cabinet formation", "hasMore": "true", "ID": 44866, "important": "False", "likesCounter": 0, "photoCounter": 0, "time": "20:47", "timeStamp": "2\/2\/2011 8:48:18 PM", "timeStatus": "True", "Title": "Bazzi: Berri endeavors to facilitate cabinet formation", "Type": "Politics", "videoCounter": 0, "viewsCounter": 0 }, {"audioCounter": 0, "commentsCounter": 0, "Exceprt": "Saker via Future News: Opening files era has ended, Gen. Aoun can\u0027t open any corruption files since his allies were the pioneers of corruption", "hasMore": "false", "ID": 44865, "important": "False", "likesCounter": 0, "photoCounter": 0, "time": "20:41", "timeStamp": "2\/2\/2011 8:45:36 PM", "timeStatus": "True", "Title": "Saker via Future News: Opening files era has ended, Gen. Aoun can\u0027t open any corruption files since his allies were the pioneers of corruption", "Type": "Politics", "videoCounter": 0, "viewsCounter": 0 }, {"audioCounter": 0, "commentsCounter": 0, "Exceprt": "White House deplores violence in Egypt", "hasMore": "true", "ID": 44857, "important": "False", "likesCounter": 0, "photoCounter": 0, "time": "20:28", "timeStamp": "2\/2\/2011 8:29:26 PM", "timeStatus": "True", "Title": "White House deplores violence in Egypt", "Type": "Politics", "videoCounter": 0, "viewsCounter": 1 }, {"audioCounter": 0, "commentsCounter": 0, "Exceprt": "Baabda sources via MTV: President Suleiman works on a consensus curriculum hoping for the formation of a national unity cabinet, if this does not happen, the cabinet will be political inlaid with technocrats", "hasMore": "false", "ID": 44855, "important": "False", "likesCounter": 0, "photoCounter": 0, "time": "20:20", "timeStamp": "2\/2\/2011 8:23:14 PM", "timeStatus": "True", "Title": "Baabda sources via MTV: President Suleiman works on a consensus curriculum hoping for the formation of a national unity cabinet, if this does not happen, the cabinet will be political inlaid with technocrats", "Type": "Politics", "videoCounter": 0, "viewsCounter": 0 }, {"audioCounter": 0, "commentsCounter": 0, "Exceprt": "An American senior official to Reuters: expects pressure on Mubarak by the army after street violence", "hasMore": "false", "ID": 44853, "important": "True", "likesCounter": 0, "photoCounter": 0, "time": "20:18", "timeStamp": "2\/2\/2011 8:20:14 PM", "timeStatus": "True", "Title": "An American senior official to Reuters: expects pressure on Mubarak by the army after street violence", "Type": "Politics", "videoCounter": 0, "viewsCounter": 0 }, {"audioCounter": 0, "commentsCounter": 0, "Exceprt": "The disappearance of the Al-Arabia correspondence Ahmed Abdullah in Egypt after clashing with Mubarak supporters", "hasMore": "false", "ID": 44851, "important": "True", "likesCounter": 0, "photoCounter": 0, "time": "20:17", "timeStamp": "2\/2\/2011 8:18:28 PM", "timeStatus": "True", "Title": "The disappearance of the Al-Arabia correspondence Ahmed Abdullah in Egypt after clashing with Mubarak supporters", "Type": "Politics", "videoCounter": 0, "viewsCounter": 0 } ], "ID": 22, "Name": "EN Live", "totalNews": 2997 } ] }}
```

My python script:

```
import json;
f = open("test.txt");
d = json.load(f);
for i in d:
    print(i);
```

My output:

```
Sections
```

That is all I'm getting. I would like to end up with a list of "Articles"  and their properties. I've tried looking at the official Python documentation but I found it to be a little vague.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `for i in d` loop, you are looping over the keys of a dictionary. The dictionary only contains one top level key, namely 'Sections', which is why you see only that output.

I do not fully understand the structure of your JSON, but it appears you want something like this:

```
for aritcle in d['Sections']['Section'][0]['Article']:
      print article
```

That will print all the articles out.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the prompt answer! This solved my problem! I am still starting out with Python and I don't fully understand the dict structure yet. Thanks again !

Comment: No problem - another neat trick is that most (all?) JSON is also valid Python code. You can directly copy and paste JSON into the Python interpreter. This is nice for experimentation. When it comes to the application, though, best to stick with the json module.

Comment: Not all JSON code is valid Python, but much of it. For instance, JSON maps the boolean values True/False to true/false and Python's None to null. After all, it's "_Javascript_ object notation". :)

Comment: @jellybean, ah, good point, I knew I would forget something like that :)

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON data Sections is the outer-most data and occurs only once. Thus the output is also the expected output, as [json.load](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load) will parse the list into a python object.

You can access the sections members by doing a for-loop for Sections, then for each section another for loop to get each article.

Answer (score 0):

It should either be:

```
for i in d.items():
    print(i);
```

or be:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print k, v
```

where you take the key and value into separate variables.

d is a python dictionary and you have to iterate over its keys and values.